# 特定のViewのみ読み込みたくないjavascriptがある。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

controllerが10個あり、対応するviewも同じ数だけある場合
6個のviewで使っているjavascriptを１個のファイルとしてapp/asset/javascript/以下に置きました。

その後、適用したいviewとは別の1個のviewがそのjavascriptの内容と競合してしまいそのviewのみ適用したくないという状況になりました。

こういう事が起こった場合どのようにするのがスマートでしょうか？

補足

起こっている競合は、datetimepickerが二重にかかってしまうという事です。

6個のviewでは共通のオプションでの適用だったのでまとめましたが、別の1個の方では別のオプションで適用しようとし、こちらは**app/asset/javascript/該当のcontroller名.js**に書きました。

Comment: 起こっている競合について補足しました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

特定のViewのみ読み込みたくないjavascriptということは、特定のViewでのみ読み込みたいと同じことなので、以下のように設定することで可能です。

現状が以下の構成だとします

- app/assets/javascripts/

  - application.js
  - 共通で読み込みたい.js
  - 特定のViewのみ読み込みたい.js

これを以下のように変更します

- app/assets/javascripts/

  - application.js
  - common/

    - 共通で読み込みたい.js
  - 特定のViewのみ読み込みたい.js

app/assets/javascripts/application.jsを変更します

```
- //= require_tree .
+ //= require_tree ./common
```

これで、commonフォルダ以外の物は指定しないかぎり読み込まれなくなります。

特定のViewのview.html.hamlに以下を追記します

```
+ javascript_include_tag '特定のViewのみ読み込みたい.js'
```

config/application.rbに以下を追記します

```
+ config.assets.precompile += Rails.root + 'app/assets/javascripts/特定のViewのみ読み込みたい.js'
```

以上で、目的を果たせるかと思います。

---

しかしながら、私は、「全てのページで常に読み込んでも問題ないようにjsを組む」のが一番スマートだと思います。